# Alter values in a column using a foreach before databind gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource

i have written this much ...but how i assign the encryptedstatusid to the listDTO for databind?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<DTO> listDto;
   IApplication engine;

   try
   {
      engine = new Engine();
      listDto = engine.ReadHistory(Session["UserID"].ToString());

      foreach (DTO iterDTO in listDto)
      {
         iterDTO.EncryptedStatusId = Triple.Encrypt(iterDTO.StatusId.ToString());

         //how i assign the encryptedstatusid to the listDTO for databind?????????????

      }

      this.dvHistory.DataSource = listDto;
      this.dvHistory.DataBind();

   }
   catch (Exception )
   {
      throw ;                
   }
   finally
   {
      engine = null;
   }
}
```

Problem is i m getting the encryttedstatusid to the iterDTO , but the satasource is a list , i want to assign encry
pted status id to the listDto, then only it will show in grid

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Is the `EncryptedStatusId` column databound in your GridView?

Comment: u cud keep a counter and do listDTO[counter] = statusID, forget not to increment the counter ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use another list to do this as an existing list can't be updated while iterating. Refer the following code:

```
  engine = new Engine();
  listDto = engine.ReadHistory(Session["UserID"].ToString());

  List<DTO> listDtoNew=new List<DTO>();

  foreach (DTO iterDTO in listDto)
  {
     iterDTO.EncryptedStatusId = Triple.Encrypt(iterDTO.StatusId.ToString());

     listDtoNew.add(iterDTO);

  }

  this.dvHistory.DataSource = listDtoNew;
  this.dvHistory.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps..